# delete a string using fgets

Tags: c

I have a normal text file as below:

```
Debdipta
1234567 8
rajat
123432 4
Kaushik
685784 7
djghkvnfj
213122 6
```

I want to delete a string from this file ex:below-

```
Debdipta
1234567 8
Kaushik
685784 7
djghkvnfj
213122 6
```

You can see that rajat and its corresponding field is deleted:

I want to do this trough C?
I can file this string and put file pointer there through following code:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
while(!feof(fp))
{
    fgets(strFileMem, MAX_PATH, fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    if( NULL == strstr(strName, strFileMem) )
    {
        break;
    }
}
int ierr = fputs(" ", fp);
ierr = fputs(" ", fp);
```

Any idea what to put in fputs???

any other code?

thanks

Comment: you need to store the txt file in a well format, such as add semicolon at the end of the string or any delimiter then you can easily check for that delimiter. Or you can use xml or json to store text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible pseudo-code solution:

```
while(fgets())
{
    if (!is_string_i_want_to_throw_away())
        fputs()
}
```

The biggest problem you have, is that you want to write to the same file you read from. This is not easy. It's much easier to read from the original file, while writing to a temporary file. When done, rename (or copy) the temporary file to the original file.

Comment: Or even better: replace `fgets()` with a `getrecord()` call that reads 2 lines, and replace `fputs()` with a `putrecord()` call that writes 2 lines.